# insert statement issues with cloudera

Tags: sql, cloudera, insert-statement

I am somewhat new to Hadoop. My company is using Cloudera. I generally use DBVisualizer to connect. I am having a weird, seemingly very simple, issue and I can't figure out what the problem is. What am I doing wrong?

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE
    table1
    (
        origin string,
        destination string,
        miles float
    );
```

I try to insert data:

```
insert into table1 (origin, destination, miles) values ('Test1','Test2',99.9)
```

I get the following message:

> 15:24:06  [INSERT - 0 row(s), 4.684 secs]  Command processed. No rows were affected
>   ... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 4.684/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 1 warnings, 0 errors]

No matter what I do, I can't seem to insert data into any tables I create with an insert statement.

I should also mention that I have tried using Hue with both Hive and Impala and have the same issue.

Comment: do you get the same warning with insert into table1 values ('Test1','Test2',99.9)

Comment: Yes I do get the same warning.

Answer (score 0):

So I was finally able to get in touch with one of the admins that manages our Cloudera installation and this is what he told me:

> This is where things are rather different than a true relational database. You have to upload the raw data files using the File Browser functionality in Hue, and then map a schema over top of it. **The JDBC drivers being used by dbVisualizer and other query tools aren’t up to the task, they just select data, no inserting, updating, or deleting.**

So there we have it. Can't be done with JDBC drivers through dbvisualizer. (Don't quote me on that, I didn't do any research, I just took my DB admin's word for it and moved on to my next project.)